# Anchor Tag in chrome not working properly?Is this a chrome Bug?

Tags: html, google-chrome, anchor

I have a site http://rethinkwaste.com.au/ .  When clicking on the very first slide I have a anchor set up

```
<div id="illegal"></div>
```

On the first load out in google chrome this seems to jump back up to the top of the page. Is this a chrome bug?

If I then refresh or load page from slider link it seems to work ok.

Comment: on which page or link you are seeing this behavior

Comment: link from the first slide on the homepage

Comment: you mean on main slide image ?

Comment: yes links to http://rethinkwaste.com.au/out-and-about/#illegal

Comment: you need to remove one illegal id if you see there two div that have illegal ID

Comment: view-source:http://rethinkwaste.com.au/out-and-about/#illegal and find this id="illegal"

Comment: I removed one and still have issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think its a [Chrome bug](https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/google-chrome-doesnt-follow-hash-pointers-in-the-url/4915). So After some searching i found this solution.

```
jQuery(window).load(function(){
    var hashNum = 0;
    if (window.location.hash != ''){
        hashNum = window.location.hash.replace("#illegal", "");   
        console.log('hashNum: ' + hashNum); 
    };
    hashMenu = jQuery("#illegal").offset().top;
      jQuery('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: hashMenu
    }, 1000);

});
```

Comment: This fixes the issue but i get some funky bouncing on all browsers except chrome on pc.

Comment: in this case y don't u detect chrome and then run this code

Comment: Is there a way to do this without jQuery? I don't want to use jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

Issue might be due to duplicate id **#illegal**, from your website code I can see this id used twice. Remove unwanted or use unique id and try. It should work

[image]

Comment: removed it still a issue